# Properly structuring array with placeholder info until filled with selected object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is kind of a confusing question and I am not sure how to Google it properly so I apologize if its been answered already. I am trying to create a build-your-own product type of app that allows a user to choose each part of their finished good and I am not sure how I should structure my data to store the users selections correctly. Right now I have a array structured like this:

```
selectedParts: [
    {
      component: "color",
      selected: null,
    },
    {
      component: "wheels",
      selected: null,
    },
    {
      component: "size",
      selected: null,
    },
    (...etc.)
  ],
```

and as they select their choice it fills in the appropriate object's 'selected' field with the part object. Here is the function I run to fill that array (I am using React and the array is in my state):

```
onSelectPart = part => {
    let selectionIndex = this.state.selectedParts.findIndex(
      i => i.component === this.state.partCategory
    )
    let cloneArray = [...this.state.selectedParts]

    cloneArray[selectionIndex].selected = part

    this.setState({
      selectedParts: cloneArray,
    })
}
```

The part is put into the array by finding the index of the category they are currently choosing from then cloning the array and adding the part into the cloned array using the index then pushing the new array to the state.

This feels wrong to me and more complicated than it should be. I want to try to keep it all in one array so that I can map through it at the end and print out their complete order summary easily but if that is the wrong approach to this what would be the recommended way to go? Would nesting objects in an 'Order' object be a good way to do this rather than using an array?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the choice of which data structure to use, then making `selectedParts` an object will be easier for you and much better for performance as you can access an object in constant time (you don't have to loop through each time). The property would be the `component` and value would the `part` object:

```
selectedParts: {
  color: null,
  wheels: null,
  size: null,
  ...
}
```

Then to update it, you'll still want to copy and update, but is much easier:

```
const onSelectPart = part => {
  const selectedParts = {...this.state.selectedParts}; 
  selectedParts[this.state.partCategory] = part; // using "computed names"
  this.setState({ selectedParts });
}
```

At the end you can print the order looping over the `selectedParts` entries:

```
const printOrderSummary = selectedParts => {
  // Note: [category, part] is just key, value of your object
  for (let [category, part] of Object.entries(selectedParts)) {
    if (part === null) part = 'Not selected'; // or skip the category, etc.

    // this would be whatever you're currently doing to map your order
    console.log(`${category}: ${part}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: I did it a little differently, let me know if this is a good way of doing it as well please :). I did what you said and switched selectedParts to an object then I just Object.assign the new part into the selectedParts object using the partCategory to find the key. So the code looks like this:
addToOrder = part => {
    let { partCategory } = this.state
    let order = this.state.order
    Object.assign(order[partCategory], part)
  } (this.state.order is selectedParts I just switched the name)

Comment: @BenCavenagh I had to check that one for a second! Won't go too much into detail but short answer is wouldn't recommend. Usually you'll encounter an error (sometimes silently), unless the order[partCategory] is already an object, and part is an object. `order = {...this.state.order}` is the same as `order = Object.assign({}, this.state.order`. Don't do this (I'll explain why after), but just for reference, if you wanted to assign that way, it'd be better to do `Object.assign(order, {[partCategory]: part}`.

Comment: The reason to not is because you [shouldn't modify state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). React batches setState calls to improve performance so that could slow it down and in case you are passing state as as a prop to another component, that component may not re-render once its changed. That's why it's better to copy and then use `setState()` to update.

Comment: Lastly, just wanted to add that if you did want to keep it as an array, you could do your find index, updating, and set state in a one liner, but is way less readable and you are essentially doing the same thing requiring another loop (could be slow if you have a lot of items in order): `this.setState(prevState => ({selectedParts: prevState.selectedParts.map(item => item.component === prevState.partCategory ? { ...item, selected: part } : item)}));` Let me know if anything's not clear or want more explanation on one of the things. Sounds like a cool app!